# 2d Elastic Collision with Circles

Tags: c++, sfml, collision

I've seen there is a lot of posts about this already but I can't find one that relates to what I want to do,
I used the formula from here:
https://www.vobarian.com/collisions/2dcollisions2.pdf
As well as this one:
https://www.plasmaphysics.org.uk/programs/coll2d_cpp.htm
I think they area basically the same thing, now my problem is one of my circles is always static, and what I want is when the other circle hits it straight on, I want it to bounce back with the same speed, but these formulas have the circle stop still, presumably as it would pass it's energy to the other circle which would then move away.
I tried doing things like bounce = vel.x pre collision - vel.y post collision and add or subtract that to vel.x post collision and it kinda works but not really, the angles are wrong and depending on which direction the ball is coming from it may bounce up instead of down, left instead of right,
would probably require a lot of if/else statements to get to work at all.
Can someone suggest something?
here's the code for the function :

```
void Collision2(sf::CircleShape* b1, sf::CircleShape* b2, sf::Vector2f vel1,sf::Vector2f& vel2) {
        //vel1 is 0,0  but i might want to use it later
        //mass
        float m1 = 10;
        float m2 = 10;
        //normal vector
        sf::Vector2f nVec((b2->getPosition().x - b1->getPosition().x), (b2->getPosition().y - b1->getPosition().y));
        //unit vector
        sf::Vector2f uNVec(nVec / sqrt((nVec.x * nVec.x) + (nVec.y * nVec.y)));
        //unit tangent vec
        sf::Vector2f uTVec(-uNVec.y, uNVec.x);

        float v1n = (uNVec.x * vel1.x) + (uNVec.y * vel1.y);
        float v2n = (uNVec.x * vel2.x) + (uNVec.y * vel2.y);
        float v1t = uTVec.x * vel1.x + uTVec.y * vel2.y;
        float v2t = (uTVec.x * vel2.x) + (uTVec.y * vel2.y);


        //v1t and v1n after collision
        float v1tN = v1t;
        float v2tN = v2t;
        float v1nN = (v1n * (m1 - m2) + (2 * m2) * v2n) / (m1 + m2);
        float v2nN = (v2n * (m2 - m1) + (2 * m1) * v1n) / (m1 + m2);

        //new velocities
        sf::Vector2f vel1N(v1nN*uNVec);
        sf::Vector2f vel1tN(v1tN * uTVec);
        sf::Vector2f vel2N(v2nN * uNVec);
        sf::Vector2f vel2tN(v2tN * uTVec);
        vel1 = (vel1N + vel1tN);
        vel2 = (vel2N + vel2tN);

    }
```

Comment: You wrote "one of my circles is always **static**". Did you mean constant? I don't see any of parameter to function `const`. Would help to understand quicker.

Comment: Collisions are simply *Conservation of Momentum* problems. A perfectly *elastic* collisions loses no energy due to deformation of either object. In a collision between circles, the force imparted to each object is the normal force applied at the point of collision. The tangent simply defines the plane the collision force acts perpendicular to. To ensure an accurate answer can be provided, please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: by static i meant one of the circles is fixed, doesnt move when the other circle hits it, so what I wanted was like say a pinball hitting one of those circular bumper things and bouncing off.
After posting this question I fiddled about a bit more and noticed if I change the mass of the circle that moves to 0 and keep the mass of the fixed one at 10 I get the effect I want, I don't know how that's going to impact things when I add collision for 2 moving circles though.

Comment: In that case you know the rebound velocity after the collision is zero. That will allow you to work backwards with momentum and energy to fix the post collision magnitude and direction of the other circle.

Answer (score 0):

### Physics part

The sources you added illustrate the physics behind it very well. when the two balls collide they transfer momentum between them. In an elastic collision this transfer keeps the energy of the system, the same.

We can think of the collision in terms of inertia and momentum, rather than starting from velocity. The kinetic energy of a body is generally `p^2/(2m)`, so if we transfer dp from the moving body then we will have change in energy: `dE = -pdp/m + dp^2/(2m) + dp^2/(2M) = 0`. Here `m` is the moving and `M` is the stationary mass. Rearranging gives `pdp/m = dp^2*(1/(2m) + 1/(2M))`. We can consider `m = M` yielding `p = dp` (i.e. All moment is transferred (Note: this is a simplistic view, only dealing with head on collisions)). In the limit where the stationary object is massive however (`M >> m`) the result will be `dp = 2p`, simply bouncing off.

### Programming

You can achieve the results by setting `M` to the maximum allowed float value (if I recall `1/inf == NaN` in the IEEE standard so that doesn't work unfortunately). Alternatively you can do the collision within the circle by creating custom classes like:

```cpp
class Circle : public sf::CircleShape{
    public:
        virtual collide (Circle*);
}

class StaticCircle : public Circle{
    public:
        collide (Circle*) override;
}
```

in the second one you can omit any terms where you divide by the mass of the circle, as it is in essence infinite.